# Using Modernizr.prefixed in jQuery .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, modernizr, vendor-prefix

I'm not good with jQuery syntax as PHP is my thing.

I'm trying to produce a jQuery animation but with the correct vendor prefixes on multiple values, but my understanding of the usage of Modernizr.prefixed is letting me down.

What I'm trying to get is something like:

```
    $('.rightbox3d').animate({
        opacity: 1
        ,top:"60px"
        ,Modernizr.prefixed('transform'):"translateY(-200px)"
        ,Modernizr.prefixed('scale'):2
    }, 4000);
```

ie. I want to include the vendor prefixes in the list of styles that are animated, but I get syntax error - unexpected token.

I have tried using 
var transformProperty = Modernizr.prefixed ? Modernizr.prefixed('transform') : 'transform';
but it only allows listing that one style
ie: $(".rightbox3d").animate(transformProperty,"translateY(-200px)");
when what I want are multiple styles like transform, opacity, scale etc.

I notice that that line of code doesn't have brace brackets around the transformProperty part, whereas a list does
eg.
$('.rightbox3d').animate({
            opacity: 1
            ,top:"-200px"
        }, 4000, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

but I just can't get my head round it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

So, you're going to have to make a big head leap.  CSS Transitions are different than jQuery.animate.

Here's a good intro on the matter.
https://www.webkit.org/blog/138/

So, first let's recognize that we can't do the same things anymore

```
if (!Modernizr.csstransitions || Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
   // use some css
} else {
   // use some jQuery
}
```

Now, let's fill in with your example

```
if (!Modernizr.csstransitions || !Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
  // Old jQuery version
  $('.rightbox3d').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: "-200px",
    width: 2 * $('.rightbox3d').width(),
    height: 2 * $('.rightbox3d').height()
  }, 4000);
} else {
  // Modern cool version
  // The transform is moving/rotating/stretching we want to do
  // The transition is the animation we want
  $('.rightbox3d').css({
    opacity: 1,
    transform: 'translateY(-200px) scale(2)',
    transition: 'all 4000ms ease-in-out'
  });
}
```

I think that should clear it up for you. :)

Comment: this code won't work. jquery is going to call foul for trying to use computed property names

Comment: Hah, yeah, that was dirty broken code.  You'd have to slowly construct the object.  Nicely, current versions of jQuery handle vendor prefixing, so I'll update it.

Comment: Updated for penance, and I released a related thing a while back
https://github.com/robcolburn/jquery.animatetimeline